# What exactly is a Lotus Notes document's "size" field?

Tags: lotus-notes

Background is that I am trying to eliminate duplicated documents that have arisen (from a rogue replication?) in a huge database - tens of thousands of docs.  I am composing a view field that uniquely identifies a document so that I can sort on that field and remove the duplicates via LotusScript code.  Trouble is that there is a rich text "Body" field that contains most of the action/variability and you can't (AFAICS) use @Abstract in a view column...

Looking around for an alternative I can see that there is a system variable "size" which includes any attachments size, so I am tentatively using this.  I note that duplicated docs (to the eye) can differ in reported size by up to about 30 bytes.

Why the small differences?  I can code the LS to use a 30-byte leeway, but I'd like to know the reason for it. And is really 30 bytes or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably document's item `$Revisions` has one more entry. That means that the document was saved one more time.

If the cause of this "copy thousands of documents" accident was replication then you might be lucky that documents contain an item `$Conflict`. This item contains the DocumentUniqueId of the original document and you could pair them this way.

Comment: Its obvious when you see it - doh !  The $Revisions suggestion is bang on the button.  No sign of any $conflicts